# DD4T: Date component field to DateTime

Tags: dd4t

I have a date field in a tridion schema which, when published using the standard DD4T templates, becomes the component field:

```
  <Field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" FieldType="Date" XPath="tcm:Metadata/custom:Metadata/custom:date">
          <Name>dates</Name>
          <Values>
            <string>16/08/2013 18:47:16</string>
          </Values>
          <NumericValues />
          <DateTimeValues>
            <dateTime>2013-08-16T18:47:16</dateTime>
          </DateTimeValues>
          <LinkedComponentValues />
          <EmbeddedValues />
          <Keywords />
    </Field>
```

Does DD4T provide a method for converting the values of a **date** field value (string) into a DateTime object?

e.g. from **dateTimeString** to DateTime:

```
string dateTimeString metadataFields["dates"].Values[0];
```

Answer (score 10):

I was one step ahead of myself. DD4T provides the method **IField.DateTimeValue**, therefore you don't need to get the string value then convert to a DateTime, you simply go straight to the DateTime (as mpaton points out, ensure to check for values when putting the code to production):

```
if (page.MetadataFields.ContainsKey("modifyDate") && page.MetadataFields["modifyDate"] != null && page.MetadataFields["modifyDate"].DateTimeValues.Count > 0)
{   List<DateTime> myDates = metadataFields["dates"].DateTimeValues;
    DateTime myDate = myDates[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Be careful that myDates[0] is not null or you'll get an Exception when you instantiate myDate

Comment: For special field types like dates, numbers, links etc, dd4t provides a number of 'lists of values', like DateTimeValues, NumberValues, etc. Note that you must always use these lists, even if the fields are single value. The shortcut IField.Value only applies to strings (text and rich text fields).